# if I use Braintree with PayPal do I pay BOTH Braintree and PayPal?

Tags: paypal

Braintree's standard processing fee is:

> 2.9% + $0.30 per transaction

PayPal's fee for online processing is:

> a fee of 2.9% of the transaction amount plus a fixed fee based on the currency

I don't want to pay both.  Do I pay both fees if I use Braintree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree. If you have any further questions, please contact our [support](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/) team.</sub>

For direct credit card transactions, you will pay the Braintree fees. For PayPal transactions you will pay the PayPal processing rates. Although you will be following two pricing schedules, you will not pay duplicate fees on each transaction.

Comment: So when the buyer makes a payment with their credit card, and the payment goes into my PayPal account, I will get the amount the buyer paid, *less* the Braintree fee.  But the buyer also has the option to pay with their PayPal account to my PayPal account?

Comment: To be clear, if you're accepting credit cards through PayPal, then you will only be paying PayPal fees on those transactions. Any transaction processed through PayPal will incur the PayPal fees. When you process with Braintree, you will pay the Braintree fees.